# Copy separated columns from Active sheet to the first empty row of another sheet and merge both columns (in the target sheet)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to find a way to copy two different continuous ranges (with columns right next to each other, for example: A;B;C and the second G;H;I); and paste it into the first empty row of another sheet, but this time I would like them merged in a continuum. (What once was “A;B;C”, “G;H;I” now I want it all in the first empty row of a new sheet but now “A;B;C;D;F;G” – note that D;F;G are G;H;I)

The code that I come up with was this one but it justs pastes the second range bellow the first one

```
Sub copy ()

lastrowa = Sheets("DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:T1346").Copy Sheets("DATA").Rows(lastrowa) & 
_ActiveSheet.Range("AC5:AH1346").Copy Sheets("DATA").Rows(lastrowa)

End Sub
```

I also tried to concatenate but it just freezes the process (never understood if it was even correct)

Notice that for `range A5:T1346` I want it to be followed by `AC5:AH1346`; merged into a continuum (meaning that AC column should become U column) in the first empty row of sheet “DATA”

Any sugestions
Thks in advance

Comment: Range of columns A;B;C;D;F;G is not a continuous range, what about E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub copy ()
    dim lastrowa as long

    lastrowa = workSheets("DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    with ActiveSheet
         .Range("A5:T1346").Copy workSheets("DATA").cells(lastrowa, "A") 
         .Range("AC5:AH1346").Copy workSheets("DATA").cells(lastrowa, "U") 
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: I think there should be lastrowa +1

Comment: No, lastrowa is already offset from the last populated cell's row.

Comment: True, I've missed it. Deceptive variable name.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thks